# Python multi-threaded program using global Queues do not release memory after Queue.get() even when the queues are empty

Tags: python, queue, pipeline, python-multithreading

I am trying to build a pipeline to read images from a folder, pre-process them, run inference with a CNN model, and save the output to disk. There are four different functions to do the four aforementioned tasks. I start a thread for each task and make communication possible between them using global queues in python. At the end of a run, all the queues would be popped empty and they shouldn't occupy any space. But, Python is not freeing the memory occupied by these queues even though the queues are empty.

What am i doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import cv2
import os
program_start_time = time.perf_counter()


def generate_rectify_map(width,height):
    distCoeff = np.zeros((4,1),np.float64)
    distCoeff[0,0] = -0.000057 # test_video : -0.00001999, sticthing : -0.0000155   -0.000015 (2300*1120)  -0.00006 (1150*560)
    distCoeff[1,0] = 0.0
    distCoeff[2,0] = 0.0
    distCoeff[3,0] = 0.0
    cam = np.eye(3,dtype=np.float32)
    cam[0,0] = 10.
    cam[1,1] = 10.
    cam[0,2] = width/2.0
    cam[1,2] = height/2.0

    rmapx, rmapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cam, distCoeff, np.eye(3), cam, (width, height),cv2.CV_32FC1)
    return rmapx,rmapy

def remap_image(img, rmapx,rmapy,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR):
    ext_img = np.zeros((560,1150))
    image = cv2.resize(img,(960,540))
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
    ext_img[10:550,95:1055] = image    
    img = cv2.remap(ext_img, rmapx, rmapy, interpolation, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return img

def read_images(count):
    global FILENAME_LIST,IMGARRAY_QUEUE
    while True:
        try:
            filepath = FILENAME_LIST.get(block=True)

            FILENAME_LIST.task_done()
            image = cv2.imread(filepath)
            IMGARRAY_QUEUE.put([image,filepath])
            print("************Image read*************")
        except:            
            time.sleep(0.01)

def image_capture(count):
    global FILENAME_LIST
    for enum,files in enumerate(os.listdir("/mnt/workspace/Anirudh/warehouse_mezzanine/pipeline/inference_test/preprocess_frames_test")):
        FILENAME_LIST.put(os.path.join("/mnt/workspace/Anirudh/warehouse_mezzanine/pipeline/inference_test/preprocess_frames_test",files))
        time.sleep(.001)
        print("Image Captured")
    print("*******IMAGE CAPTURE COMPLETE***********")

def flatten_images():
    global IMGARRAY_QUEUE,INFER_QUEUE,rmapx,rmapy,remap_fps,OUT_QUEUE
    while True:
        try:
            image,filename = IMGARRAY_QUEUE.get(block=True)

            IMGARRAY_QUEUE.task_done()
            remap_start = time.perf_counter()
            remapped = remap_image(image,rmapx,rmapy)
            print("Image Flattened")
            remapped_resized = cv2.resize(remapped,(544,320))
            remap_fps.append(1/(time.perf_counter()-remap_start))
            INFER_QUEUE.put([remapped,remapped_resized])

        except:            
            time.sleep(0.01)

def write_output():
    global OUT_QUEUE
    while True:
        try:
            image = OUT_QUEUE.get(block=False)

            OUT_QUEUE.task_done()
            print("POPPING")
            cv2.imwrite("foo/image.png",image)
        except:
            time.sleep(0.01)


FILENAME_LIST=Queue()
IMGARRAY_QUEUE=Queue()
INFER_QUEUE=Queue()
OUT_QUEUE=Queue()
remap_fps = []
rmapx,rmapy = generate_rectify_map(1150,560)

CAPTURE_THREADS = 1
thread_list = []
for i in range(CAPTURE_THREADS):
    thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=image_capture,args = (i,)))
READING_THREADS = 4
for i in range(READING_THREADS):
    thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=read_images,args = (i,)))
FLATTEN_THREADS = 1
for i in range(FLATTEN_THREADS):
    thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=flatten_images))
WRITING_THREADS = 1
for i in range(WRITING_THREADS):
    thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=write_output))
count = 0

for i in thread_list:
    print("starting")
    i.start()

time.sleep(7) # to simulate actual time delay that happens in an actual situation. 

while True:    
    try:
        if count==2768:
            print("*******************Completed***********************")
            break
        remapped,remapped_resized = INFER_QUEUE.get(block=False)
        if remapped==None:
            OUT_QUEUE.put(None)
            break
        INFER_QUEUE.task_done()
        time.sleep(.006) #to simulate model inference time
        OUT_QUEUE.put(remapped)    
        print("Inference Run")
        count+=1
        
    except:        
        time.sleep(0.01)

print(time.perf_counter()-program_start_time)
print("printing q size")
print(FILENAME_LIST.qsize())
print(IMGARRAY_QUEUE.qsize())
print(INFER_QUEUE.qsize())
print(OUT_QUEUE.qsize())
for i in thread_list:
    i.join()
    

# q = Queue()
# def add():
#     global q
#     for i in range(450):
#         q.put(np.random.randint(1,255,size=(1080,1920,3)))
#         print("ADDING TO THE QUEUE")
        

# def remove():
#     global q
#     while True:
#         try:
#             q.get(block=True)
#             print("REMOVING FROM THE QUEUE")
#         except:
#             time.sleep(0.01)

# add_threads = 3
# for i in range(add_threads):
#     threading.Thread(target=add).start()





# time.sleep(8)
# while True:
#     try:
#         q.get()
#         print("POPPING")
#     except:
#         time.sleep(.01)
```

I tried to reproduce the problem using the code presented above and observed the same memory issue that we faced in the actual pipeline.